# How can I select data from two differents servers?

Tags: mysql

I have two databases: `data1` and `data2` in two different servers (`server1` and `server2`).

I am trying to join two tables of my two databases in MySQL like this:

```
SELECT left(a.code,9) as fourn,
       SUM(b.price) as total
FROM data1.product as a
JOIN data2.my_items as b ON a.fourn = b.left(p_code)
```

and this is the error I get when I run the query in `server1`:

> SELECT command denied to user 'slave'@'' for table 'my_items'

Comment: Can you add to your question some explanation about what problems do you have? or what's the error?

Comment: @oNare SELECT command denied to user 'slave'@'' for table 'my_items '

Comment: Which server (1 or 2) are you connected to when you run this query?

Comment: @ypercube i run query in server1.

Comment: Did you check if the user `slave` is with the host empty in table `mysql.users`? You put ` 'slave'@'' ` and this means that the user `slave` from host `''` is trying to access to table `my_items` and it doesn't have permissions for `SELECTs`. I agree with @ypercube.

Comment: There is no easy way to access multiple instances with the same query. See this question for some options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810349/mysql-cross-server-select-query

Comment: @oNare i have a permission just to select but not insert,update,delete :)

Answer (score 2):

**Federated storage engine can help you.**

In mysql, you can achieve this by using federated storage engine. It allows you to access tables from different server. Once you reference the table from specific server, you can use it. You can get more details about 
[federated storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/federated-description.html). Now you can join two tables from different servers. [how to use federated engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html)

**ETL tools can help you like Talend data integration**

Talend is open source tool which is ETL tool uses in data ware housing. It have nice UI, you can learn it in short duration. Here you can create many Mysql or database connections  and use the different connections for different tables, can join whatever as you need.

Comment: Thank u a lot for ur answer. I installed talend data integration i will learn how i can work with.

Comment: So using Talend i can join between two databases on different servers?!!

Comment: @Sarah yes, whatever any type of operation you can perform with clicks

Comment: @Sarah for first time use tmysqlinput for tables, tmap component for joins